Хочу получить ключ по значению словаря
Я хочу вывести model, по значению x3/x4/x5, код представлен ниже, подскажите как лучше это сделать ?
my_dict = {
        "Mashina": "BMW",
        "model": ["x3", "x4", "x5"],
        "benzin": 2.0
}
print(my_dict)


В данном случае не понятно какой в этом практический смысл. Если нужно например по модели получать характеристики - добавьте отдельный словарь, где ключи - модели, в значениях - характеристики.

Если я вас верно понял, то можно перебрать словарь в цикле:
def search_to_dict(value_to_find, dictionary):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if isinstance(value, list) and value_to_find in value:
            return key
        
my_dict = {
    "Mashina": "BMW",
    "model": ["x3", "x4", "x5"],
    "benzin": 2.0
}

search_value = "x3"

print(search_to_dict(search_value, my_dict)) # model

